# Moving page number for new chapters pages to the top

Tags: page-numbering, koma-script, classicthesis

Using classic-thesis, and using \pagestyle{scrheadings} the first page of new chapters shows the page number at the bottom left/right corner of the page. I would like to change only the position of the page number and moving it to the top left/right. I searched and I guess that I have to use something like:

```
\deftripstyle{pgnumbottomcenter}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark{}}{}% Here I have to modify something
\pagestyle{pgnumbottomcenter}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumbottomcenter}
```

What should I modify to move the page number to the top, (maintening all others characteristics of the page number style)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [KOMA-script document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) (section **5.2. Defining Own Page Styles**) mentions the interface for `\deftripstyle`:

```
\deftripstyle{<name>}[<LO>][<LI>]{<HI>}{<HC>}{<HO>}{<FI>}{<FC>}{<FO>}
```

This allows you to set `H`eaders and `F`ooters for `I`nner, `O`uter and `C`entred locations on the page. Below I defined the page style `pgnumtopouter` that places `\pagemark` inside `<HO>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% \deftripstyle{<name>}[<LO>][<LI>]{<HI>}{<HC>}{<HO>}{<FI>}{<FC>}{<FO>}
\deftripstyle{pgnumbottomcenter}{}{}{}{}{\pagemark}{}% Here I have to modify something
\pagestyle{pgnumbottomcenter}
\deftripstyle{pgnumtopouter}{}{}{\pagemark}{}{}{}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumtopouter}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]

\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-7]
\end{document}
```